# Distinct in KQL always gives same records

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a task to write kql to get all the users that exist within a given radius of a given lat/long. I have written the following query and if I do not do distinct I get different users with varying date supplied, but when I use distinct, it always gives same 46 records. Any idea what can be the problem in the query?

```
TableName
        | where Date <> ''
        | where Date >= todatetime('2022-11-07 00:00:00')
        | where  Date <= todatetime('2022-11-08 17:38:00')
        | where acos(sin(25.27323946648474) * sin(Latitude) + cos(25.27323946648474) * cos(Latitude) * cos(Longitude - (51.499766541858236))) * 6371 <= (50)
        | where StayType == 'I'
        | join kind=inner User on $left.Major == $right.Major
        | join kind=inner User on $left.Minor == $right.Minor
        | project DocumentNumber,DocumentTypeString,tostring(DocumentExpiryDate),HCNO, NameEnglish,NameArabic,Gender,NationalityName,Vaccinated,PhoneType
        | distinct DocumentNumber, DocumentTypeString, NameEnglish,NameArabic,Gender,NationalityName,Vaccinated,PhoneType,HCNO
        | order by DocumentTypeString asc
```

Comment: **(1)** The issue is not clear. Please remember that we don't have access to your data. If you claim that the result set is changing between runs, please supply some evidence that would backup this claim.  **(2)** KQL provides an extensive support for geo queries, including the function [geo_distance_2points()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74359075/distinct-in-kql-always-gives-same-records). If you model your data correctly a search operation like this could leverage an index (instead of doing a full scan).

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was because of the field Minor that has same values for different records. Changing the join statement as below solved the problem.

```
| join kind=inner User on $left.Minor == $right.Minor and $left.Major == $right.Major
```